# package com.google.android.gms.maps.model does not exist

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I am in **Android Studio** and this is a **NON GRADLE** project.

I have installed google play services, and google repository through sdk manager. I have imported google-play-services_lib as a module and added the google-play-services.jar as a library.

Yet for some reason my android-maps-utils files can't find my play services references.

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
```

in com.google.maps.android.clustering.Cluster.java says model doesn't exist.I can see the file in the play services library inside my project as shown below:

[image]

So why can't this file pick it up?:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add dependencies for my project and each of my 3rd party libraries.

In Android Studio File > Project Structure > Libraries > choose a library > on the bottom of the dialog there should be a + button. Click that and then add dependencies. I think I added them as libraries (whatever the second option was)